# Multiple locations from location services in ios?

Tags: objective-c, location-services

My question is about the getting the multiple locations from #CLLocation manager and how to make the x and y axis in the objective C.

Comment: i m getting the latitude and longitude of only one point. i want to get the points of the multiple locations which is searched by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all location stored at delegates method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The delegate above is deprecated in iOS 6. Now the following should be used:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

In order to get the last position, simply get the last object of the array:

```
[locations lastObject]
```